# EF6: How to combine two different count() queries into one?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

```
var filesCount = files.Where(f => f.ParentId == folderId).Count();
var foldersCount = folders.Where(f => f.ParentId == folderId).Count();
```

My main object is to reduce the round-trip to database from two to one.

Background

- .NET Framework 4.5.2
- Entity Framework 6

Comment: Create a Stored Procedure with 2 OUT parameters?

Comment: It's Entity Framework 6.

Comment: Is there a navigational property from folder to files? and from folder to sub folders? Please include your entity classes in the question.

Comment: Navigation property can't be used because I am looking for files and folders underneath the same parent folder. Basically there is no relationship apart from parent id.

Comment: @Kyaw I know that you are using Enity. But even in Entity, you have the possibility to work with Stored Procedures.

Comment: I think that you can do it if you have a navigational property from folder to sub folders and from folder to files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this if you have navigational properties from folder to sub folders and from folder to files:

```
var result =
    folders
    .Where(x => x.Id == folderId)
    .Select(x => new
    {
        FolderCount = x.SubFolders.Count(),
        FileCount = x.Files.Count()
    })
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: It makes sense. Let me try and get back to you.